# How to receive Mediafire's API information?

Tags: c#, winforms

Alright, so I'm kind of new with this API stuff and I'm trying to get API information using some function to send me signature, session etc.. Could you help me about it? I couldn't find any tutorial on the web..

Comment: You should be a bit more specific about a particular problem you are having.  This question is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have a ready function I scripted not so long ago. I don't mind sharing it with you.

```
        //Mediafire API Info
        private static string url = "HTTPS://www.mediafire.com/api/1.2/user/get_session_token.php?";
        private static string mf_email = "YOUR_EMAIL", mf_password = "YOUR_PASS", mf_app_id = "API_APP_ID", mf_api_key = "API_KEY", mf_signature = Mediafire_GetSignature();
        private static string mf_secret_key, mf_ekey, mf_pkey, mf_session, mf_response, mf_time, mf_callsig;
        private static string mf_folder_key = "FOLDER_ID"; // Folder to upload files to.
        // END

        public static string Mediafire_GetSignature()
        {
            string data = mf_email + mf_password + mf_app_id + mf_api_key;
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            byte[] hash;
            using (SHA1 sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
                hash = sha1.ComputeHash(bytes);
            string hashString = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
            return hashString;
        }
        public static void Mediafire_GetInfo()
        {
            mf_response = Mediafire_GetSessionToken();
            if (!mf_response.ToLower().Contains("<result>success</result>"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Mediafire_GetInfo: ERROR #1.");
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
            {
                string[] sess = { "<session_token>", "</session_token>" };
                mf_session = mf_response.Substring(mf_response.IndexOf(sess[0]) + sess[0].Length, mf_response.IndexOf(sess[1]) - mf_response.IndexOf(sess[0]) - sess[1].Length + 1);
                /*string[] secret = { "<secret_key>", "</secret_key>" }; // token_version=2 only
                mf_secret_key = mf_response.Substring(mf_response.IndexOf(secret[0]) + secret[0].Length, mf_response.IndexOf(secret[1]) - mf_response.IndexOf(secret[0]) - secret[1].Length + 1);*/
                string[] pkey = { "<pkey>", "</pkey>" };
                mf_pkey = mf_response.Substring(mf_response.IndexOf(pkey[0]) + pkey[0].Length, mf_response.IndexOf(pkey[1]) - mf_response.IndexOf(pkey[0]) - pkey[1].Length + 1);
                string[] ekey = { "<ekey>", "</ekey>" };
                mf_ekey = mf_response.Substring(mf_response.IndexOf(ekey[0]) + ekey[0].Length, mf_response.IndexOf(ekey[1]) - mf_response.IndexOf(ekey[0]) - ekey[1].Length + 1);
                /*string[] time = { "<time>", "</time>" }; // token_version=2 only
                mf_time = mf_response.Substring(mf_response.IndexOf(time[0]) + time[0].Length, mf_response.IndexOf(time[1]) - mf_response.IndexOf(time[0]) - time[1].Length + 1);*/
                CopyToClipboard(mf_session);
            }
            if (mf_session == null || /*mf_secret_key == null || */mf_pkey == null || mf_ekey == null/* || mf_time == null*/)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Mediafire_GetInfo: ERROR #2.");
                Application.Exit();
            }
            if (FirstGetInfo)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connected to Mediafire successfully..");
                FirstGetInfo = false;
            }
        }

        public static string Mediafire_GetSessionToken()
        {
            try
            {
                string posturl = url + "signature=" + mf_signature + "&email=" + mf_email + "&password=" + mf_password + "&application_key=" + mf_api_key + "&application_id=" + mf_app_id + "&token_version=1&response_format=xml";
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(posturl);
                byte[] bytes;
                bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(posturl);
                request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
                request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                request.Method = "POST";
                Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
                HttpWebResponse response;
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                    return responseStr;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception s)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Session Token Error. " + s.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Of course, change mf_email to the email you use to sign in, mf_password to your password, mf_app_id to your API's app id provided by Mediafire (should be 5 numbers if I recall correctly) and mf_api_key to your API's key provided by Mediafire (should be long, random characters). Both api_key and app_id are provided [here](https://www.mediafire.com/#settings/applications). I hope you'll figure out how to use it correctly.
Enjoy!